# Find objects in one site but not another without using the set operation diff

Tags: scala

Two sets, s1 and s2, of Foo objects, where

```
case class Foo(id: Long, attri01: String) {
  override def hashCode: Int = { 
    val prime = 41
    prime * attri01.hashCode
 }
 override def equals(o: Any): Boolean = o match {
   case Foo(_, attri01) => attri01 == this.attri01
   case => false
 }
}
```

The equals and hashCode methods are override for a data comparison.

Now, I need to find out all objects in the s1, but not in the s2. I can't use

```
s1.diff(s2)
```

due to the equals/hashCode method override. It likely shall use the filter

```
s1.filter(_.id ...)
```

or creating a map with the ID field as its key and its object as the value for the first set and remove any entries in the second set.

What is a good approach to solve this problem in the Scala way(s)?

Update:

I was thinking of something like the followings:

```
val set2IDs = s2.map(a => a.id)
val result = s1.map(Foo(id, _) => !set2IDs.contains(id))
```

The second line of code doesn't work, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case class FooWrapper(id:Long)(val foo:Foo)

def wrap(foo:Foo) = new FooWrapper(foo.id)(foo)

val result = s1.map(wrap).diff(s2.map(wrap)).map(_.foo)
```

Comment: Thanks Madoc. It works. It is a very fancy approach.